# Is response of curl command different from a browser's one?

Tags: macos, curl

I noticed interesting thing that response via `curl` command is different from one via a *browser*. Is this common phenomenon or just specific for my query?

My command is

```
curl -sA "Chrome" -L "https://www.google.com/search?q=candy&num=100&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2010%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2010&tbm=" -o ~/out.html
```

When I type URL `https://www.google.com/search?q=candy&num=100&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2010%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2010&tbm=` into a browser (Firefox), the result shown only from 2010/1/1 to 2010/12/31. But, the response via curl command show the result of 'anytime' result.

My environment is OSX 10.8, Firefox 44.0.1, and curl 7.21.0

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220893/curl-response-different-than-response-to-request-sent-from-browser) discussing a similar topic, and tried to use `"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"` as a user agent. But, the result is the same.